# Compare results of 2 different Postman collection test runs using Newman

Tags: api, postman, newman

I am considering using Newman to run some API tests using some Postman collections that I have created. I would like to run these tests against 2 different builds of our web application and compare the results to see if our current dev build would break our production build.

Is there a way to do this currently?

I was hoping to do something like the following :

```
Newman.execute(collection, optionsBuildA, function() {

    Newman.execute(collection, optionsBuildB, function() {

        //Read in results from build A output file
        //Read in results from build B output file

        //Compare build A results to build B results
    }); 
});
```

However, this causes an EventEmitter memory leak. This is the exact message I'm getting :

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 requestExecuted listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
```

Comment: You probably fixed it already and I would be very much interested in how you did it. We're also experiencing memory leakage in the Newman module, and fixed it by generating test result JSONs via normal crontab task and then only comparing results within Node.

Comment: Sorry to say that I haven't. I tried spawning Newman in different child processes and had no luck there either.